# d.ts When write const its say not exist. why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

Hello I wonder something.

When I write like this and use const on global variable.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
declare global {
  namespace globalThis {
    const prismadb: PrismaClient;
  }
}
```

I'm taking error

`Property 'prismadb' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'.`

But when I use var instead of const my problem is fixed.

Btw Im using here

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const client = global.prismadb || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") global.prismadb = client;

export default client;
```

But I wonder why, when I use const its giving not exist error.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are going to declare it as a constant you need to set it to something. `const prismadb: PrismaClient = something;`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `global` the same as `globalThis`?

```
declare global {
  const prismadb: PrismaClient;
}
```